# Шейдер плоского освещения

Tags: освещение, шейдеры

Я хочу использовать точечный источник света для того, чтобы показать ограниченность поля зрения персонажа в игре с видом сверху. На трехмерную сцену свет ложится не так ровно, как мне нужно.

Думаю, можно создать поверхностный шейдер, который будет устанавливать уровень освещенности только в зависимости от расстояния, не учитывая нормаль. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как этот шейдер написать.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не указали деталей, так что ответ будет общим:

```
расстояние = длина вектора(положение пикселя - положение камеры);

освещенность = 1 - расстояние / максимальное расстояние видимости;

освещенность = клип(освещенность, 0, 1);

цвет пикселя = цвет материала * освещенность;
```

Comment: Если автор хочет показать поле зрения, то, думаю, имеет место быть  `освещенность = 1 - степень(расстояние / максимальное расстояние видимости, какая-то степень)`, чтобы оно резко затухало у краев, а не линейно.

Comment: Это уже на усмотрение автора вопроса. Основной принцип остается.